# How to enable smart MTU black hole detection/PLPMTUD feature for IPv6

Tags: networking, ipv6

In an article entitled "[Path MTU discovery in practice](https://blog.cloudflare.com/path-mtu-discovery-in-practice/)", it provides a way to enable smart MTU black hole detection or Packetization Layer Path MTU Discovery feature on Linux by typing these commands:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_mtu_probing
echo 1024 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_base_mss
```

However, it's for IPv4 only.

Therefore, how can I enable this feature for IPv6?

Comment: You don't need to.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Do you mean it's already enabled by default?

Comment: There's no point to setting a "base MSS" of 1024 when the minimum MTU is 1280. Besides, the _problem itself_ as described there is IPv4-only.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Where do you read the problem is IPv4-only? The article states it mostly affected IPv6 users. Ultimately the problem as described is a result of the load balancing used and applies equally to IPv4 and IPv6.

Comment: @rfc2460 It affected users of IPv6 _tunnels_, according to the article. And you can't have a MTU below 1024 in IPv6. At least not without breaking a lot of RFCs

Comment: @MichaelHampton The article does say it affected tunnels. But if you read through the details you'll realize the problem was due to variations in MTU along the path and not directly that a tunnel was used. It just so happens that tunnels tend to cause variations in MTU, but that's not the only reason why the MTU would wary. It's true that the MTU cannot be less than 1280 in IPv6, so you'd probably want a higher base MSS value with IPv6. The RFC defines the algorithm in a way that works with both IPv4 and IPv6.